# Insert range of cells to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a range with numbers obtained from a scanner (scanner puts number in that range after using it) having information like serial number and date (from B9 to C20) and a cell (L2) which indicates the number of part. After printing this data with a button (print button with macros), a button for erasing the data from this range is used. What I would like to do is to have in the erase button a macro that copies the data from the range of cells and L2 to another sheet every time the button is pressed and create a database of this. Below is the sheet with the information. 
[image]

Here's my current code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Base de datos")


Set table_list_object = Sheets("Base de datos").ListObjects("table1")


Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add


last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

the_sheet.Range("A" & last_row_with_data) = ActiveSheet.Range("B9:B20")

the_sheet.Range("B" & last_row_with_data) = ActiveSheet.Range("C9:C20")

' the_sheet.Range("C" & last_row_with_data) = ActiveSheet.Range("L2")

' the_sheet.Range("D" & last_row_with_data) = ActiveSheet.Range("L3")



End Sub
```

Comment: B9 - C20 is static, correct? Will the data always span D9 - M20? If so you can just copy a static range, if the table is not always filled out, you will need to determine the last row, in say column D. Where do you want the value in L2 to go on your new sheet?

Comment: Yes, B9-C20 is static and the table might not always be filled out. L2 would be on another column, repeated in all the rows from the data of the static range. For example, Column A will save the serial numbers, Column B Dates and Column C will have the value from L2 repeated.

Comment: So your copy range is always B9 - M20? The range that will be stored in your database that is*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to amend this to fit your needs as im not exactly sure what your criteria is, but this should get you started! First, create a sheet called "Database." I'm assuming your copy range is static. If the range is not static, you can "un-comment" out the "RCount" portion of the code and amend to set a dynamic copy range.

Currently the code will copy your range (B9:M20) and paste it on a new sheet called "Database" at the last available row on Col A.

To clear out your table, I would create another macro below this (you can just record one) with title "Macro_Title." Before "End Sub"

```
    Call Macro_Title
```

Macro

```
Public Sub Wow()

'Declare Variables
Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
Dim wsDataBase As Worksheet
Set wsOrigin = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Base de datos")
Set wsDataBase = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Database")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy/Special Paste Desired Data
Dim COPYME As Range
'Dim RCount As Integer
Dim RCount2 As Integer

'RCount = wsOrigin.Range("L" & wsOrigin.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
RCount2 = wsDataBase.Range("A" & wsDataBase.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set COPYME = wsOrigin.Range("B9:M20))
COPYME.Copy

wsDataBase.Range("A" & RCount2 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not address the range you want to copy of "L2" since you provided no instruction on where to put it. You can mimic the above. Dim a new range. Set range = wsOrigin.Range("L2"). Range.Copy, etc.

Comment: I want L2 copied in a column ("C") for every row that gets copied from the sheet. For example, If I copied 12 serial numbers and dates, L2 data should be repeated in a new column 12 times.